# Why do I get 403 forbidden when deploying laravel project with nginx?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx

I tried many answers from SO and other sites online but I can't seem to get it to work.

I get 403 forbidden error when deploying my laravel project with nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxxxx.co www.xxxxx.co;
        return 301 https://xxxxx.co$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxxxx.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxxxx.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name  xxxxx.co www.xxxxx.co;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

}
```

where `/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public` has this content, if matters:

`admin  favicon.ico  home  index.php  web.config`

On local machine, it works fine and I see the home page, but with nginx I can't make it work

**EDIT 1:**
Here are permissions on **/var/www/www.xxxxx.co**

`drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Oct 10 07:48 .`

Here are the logs from **/var/log/nginx/domains/main.xxxxx.co.error.log**

```
2020/10/10 08:19:39 [error] 19736#19736: *9 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/home/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:20:31 [error] 19736#19736: *9 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                    2020/10/10 08:20:35 [error] 19736#19736: *9 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:22:03 [error] 19776#19776: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                                           2020/10/10 08:22:04 [error] 19776#19776: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:24:03 [error] 19825#19825: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                                           2020/10/10 08:25:31 [error] 19857#19857: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:25:36 [error] 19857#19857: *3 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                                           2020/10/10 08:26:24 [error] 19873#19873: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:29:14 [error] 19908#19908: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                                           2020/10/10 08:31:44 [error] 19937#19937: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:31:48 [error] 19937#19937: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/home/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                                 2020/10/10 08:34:21 [error] 19968#19968: *1 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:36:24 [error] 19968#19968: *3 directory index of "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public/" is forbidden, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                                           2020/10/10 08:38:46 [error] 20024#20024: *2 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:38:50 [error] 20024#20024: *2 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                 2020/10/10 08:39:43 [error] 20024#20024: *2 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:40:23 [error] 20024#20024: *2 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                 2020/10/10 08:40:26 [error] 20024#20024: *2 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:53:32 [error] 20220#20220: *36 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"                     2020/10/10 08:53:46 [error] 20220#20220: *36 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:53:50 [error] 20220#20220: *41 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "www.xxxxx.co"            2020/10/10 08:54:19 [error] 20220#20220: *42 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "www.xxxxx.co"
2020/10/10 08:54:22 [error] 20244#20244: *1 open() "/var/www/www.xxxxx.co/publicindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.xxxxx.co"                  2020/10/10 09:03:03 [crit] 20322#20322: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstrea>2020/10/10 09:05:47 [crit] 20394#20394: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstrea>2020/10/10 09:05:48 [crit] 20394#20394: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstrea>2020/10/10 13:30:47 [crit] 20394#20394: *224 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.201, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /ads.txt HTTP/1.1">2020/10/10 13:54:08 [crit] 20394#20394: *257 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 195.154.61.206, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/10 13:57:53 [crit] 20394#20394: *265 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 195.154.61.206, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/10 15:15:46 [crit] 20394#20394: *350 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.203, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /ads.txt HTTP/1.1">2020/10/10 15:38:08 [crit] 20394#20394: *385 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 62.210.10.77, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstre>2020/10/10 15:38:28 [crit] 20394#20394: *387 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 195.154.63.222, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/10 17:52:32 [crit] 20394#20394: *629 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.94, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstre>2020/10/10 20:00:52 [crit] 20394#20394: *848 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.201, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstr>2020/10/10 21:00:50 [crit] 20394#20394: *900 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.95, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstre>2020/10/10 22:00:32 [crit] 20394#20394: *988 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.205, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstr>2020/10/10 23:22:15 [crit] 20394#20394: *1098 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 182.66.43.161, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/11 00:01:52 [crit] 20394#20394: *1165 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.203, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/11 04:40:28 [crit] 20394#20394: *1609 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 77.30.211.212, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/11 05:32:53 [crit] 20394#20394: *1685 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.205, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upst>2020/10/11 08:56:03 [crit] 20394#20394: *1948 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.205, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /en/desert-one HT>2020/10/11 09:30:17 [crit] 20394#20394: *1994 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 167.172.56.36, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /wp-login.php HTT>2020/10/11 11:43:53 [crit] 20394#20394: *2149 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 18.162.245.185, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /wp-login.php HT>2020/10/11 13:16:09 [crit] 20394#20394: *2324 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.66.201, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET /ads.txt HTTP/1.1>2020/10/11 13:41:01 [crit] 20394#20394: *2343 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.49.72.36, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstre>2020/10/11 13:50:54 [crit] 28196#28196: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.49.72.36, server: www.xxxxx.co, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:>
```

Comment: are the project files readable by nginx?

Comment: Check the error log. Where is your PHP `location` block? Why is the second `server` block listening on port 80?

Comment: For what its worth, here's an example of one of my working ssl confs https://pastebin.com/C4HpGvXP

Comment: @apokryfos I edit the question with details

Comment: @RichardSmith can you please clarify? I followed many default config examples but none worked

Comment: What is your server OS? Is it SELinux enabled? Do you really have PHP-FPM installed? What version? Where is it control socket file located? It is definitely not a `/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` you are trying to use. Why your nginx config included to question is different from what you uploaded to pastebin? Why your included error logs in so screwed form? Why you included error logs related to different config versions? Clean up your question and provide an actual and correct information if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Remove `$uri/` from the `try_files`. It looks like nginx checks directory listing permissions before checking if the actual directory exists (maybe)

Comment: @apokryfos it didn't work :/

Comment: @IvanShatsky I didn't upload anything to pastebin. And yes it's installed and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it.
Comment from @Ivan Shatsky made me search about PHP-FPM.
I found it was important and most examples online didn't include it in config.
I installed it via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4-cli php7.4-curl php7.4-mysql php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd php7.4-xml php7.4-mbstring php7.4-zip php7.4-soap php7.4-dev -y
```

I faced other issues but finally got it working with this config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.xxxxx.co xxxxx.co;
        return 301 https://www.xxxxx.co$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxxxx.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxxxx.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name  www.xxxxx.co xxxxx.co;
    root /var/www/www.xxxxx.co/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```